# Polymer Layout- place space between cards and responsiveness

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.1

I have a custom element where I want a row with just 2 paper cards with a 100px space between them. And of course, if the screen shrinks like on a cell phone, I want the cards to stack.

I am not sure how to place the space between the paper-cards. If I do `margin` or `padding` then when the cards are stacked on a smaller screen, they are pushed to the side and not centered.

This is rather a large element, so I just placed the main code:

```
<dom-module id="portfolio-page">
  <style>
    :host[show] {
      @apply(--layout-horizontal);
      @apply(--layout-center-justified);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: var(--paper-grey-50);
     }
       #main {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
      #main {
        width: 90%;
      }

     paper-card {
      max-width: 400px;
      min-width: 250px;
     }


    </style>

  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}">
      <div id="main">
        <div class="vertical layout">
          <div class="horizontal justified layout">
            <paper-card elevation="3" class="fancy"></paper-card>
            <paper-card elevation="3" class="fancy"></paper-card>
          </div>
        </div>
       </template>
      </template>
    </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some particularly tricky things going on here and some particularly overlapping styles trying to fix it.  The one sticking point I see if having flexible widths on your cards, that makes you need to rely on CSS calc if you also need to have a fixed 100px between the two cards.  I've rigged up the follow that follows most of the rules you've laid out, but there are of course lots of little CSS flourishes you could get into depending on what delivery requirements you have:

```
<dom-module id="portfolio-page">
  <style>
    :host[show] {
      @apply(--layout-horizontal);
      @apply(--layout-around-justified);
      @apply(--layout-wrap);
      height: 100%;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: var(--paper-grey-50);
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    paper-card {
      max-width: 400px;
      min-width: 250px;
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 700px) {
      :host[show] {
        @apply(--layout-justified);
      }
      paper-card {
        width: calc(50% - 100px);
      }
      paper-card + paper-card {
        margin-left: 100px;
      }
    }

    @media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
      :host {
        width: 90%;
      }
    }


    </style>

<template>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}">
          <paper-card elevation="3" class="fancy">Test 1</paper-card>
          <paper-card elevation="3" class="fancy">Test 2</paper-card>
  </template>
</template>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Ah, the `paper-card + paper-card` is clever. Thank you for that one.

Answer (score 0):

paper card + paper card solution would not make a space on the first card :)

I just personally did on my website simply using this code
     paper-card {
      max-width: 300px;
      min-width: 250px;
             margin: 10px;
}